# access objects from json

Tags: javascript, json

I have an ajax call that receives a json encoded object on return.

```
success: function (response) {
jsonArrayResponse =  jQuery.parseJSON(response["data"]);
autoSearchValue = jsonArrayResponse['autoresult'];
```

I want to be able to access the different parts of the decode.  This is some sample return

```
{"success":true,"message":null,"messages":null,"data":"{\"errorText\":\"\",\"autoresult\":[{\"firstname\":\"Annon\",\"lastname\":\"Brooks\",\"date_of_birth\":\"1975-12-23 00:00:00\",\"id\":\"1\"},{\"firstname\":\"Josh\",\"lastname\":\"Ferns\",\"date_of_birth\":\"2000-09-02 00:00:00\",\"id\":\"2\"},
{\"firstname\":\"Alan\",\"lastname\":\"Templeton\",\"date_of_birth\":\"1975-08-02 00:00:00\",\"id\":\"3\"}}]}
```

I've found that I can access the firstname by

```
autoSearchValue[0]['firstname'];
```

but I can't figure out how to loop through the other firstname values.  I'm guessing it's straightforward once you know how.

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: for(var I = 0; I < autoSearchValue.length; I++){autoSearchValue[I].firstname}

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

autoSearchValue is an array.  Just use an index in a loop:

```
for (let index = 0; index < autoSearchValue.length; index++) {
  autoSearchValue[index]['firstname'];
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything specific to TS in this answer.

Comment: thanks that worked:)  I tried it with a for each loop but I never thought of a plain for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to loop throught the length of the json object? Each loop will increment the counter since you get the first name with autoSearchValue[0]['firstname'] then find the next one with autoSearchValue[1]['firstname'] until the length is reached.

Comment: but how do you determine the length of the object to loop through?

Comment: you just got your answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access by iteratig over the object. As an option you can use map function to iterate over the array, the callback function will receive current value on the argument 
which you can either modify or process

```
   autoSearchValue.map((value) => {
       console.log(value.firstname)
    })
```